# one div gets bigger while the other gets smaller

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new to javascript, I'm wondering how to get .contact from a 30% width to 40% when I go with my mouse over .contact. This works, but while .contact gets bigger I want .div to get smaller from 70% width to 60%, so .div won't get under .contact.

This is what I have at the moment:

```js
var width = 30;

var maxWidth = 40;

var interval = null;

var contact = document.getElementById("contact");

function myMove() {
  interval = setInterval(function() {
    if (width>= maxWidth){
      return clearInterval(interval);
    }
    contact.style.width = ++width + "%";
  },5);
}
```

```css
.contact{
    background-color:red;
    width:30%;
    float:left;
}
.div{
    background-color: blue;
    width: 70%;
    float: right;    
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
                
        <div class="contact" id="contact" onmouseover="myMove()">                    
            <h3> Text</h3>
            <p>More textt</p>
        </div>

        <div class="div">
            <h3> Text</h3>
            <p>More textt</p>
        </div>                

</div>
```

Do you know how to do this?

Answer (score 4):

You don't need javascript for this, sibling selector works. 
Or in javascript, shrink the div on the right while expanding the div on the left.

```js
var width = 30;

var maxWidth = 40;

var interval = null;

var contact = document.getElementById("contact");
var div = document.getElementById("div");
function myMove() {
  interval = setInterval(function() {
    if (width>= maxWidth){
      return clearInterval(interval);
    }
    contact.style.width = ++width + "%";
    div.style.width = (100-width) + "%";
  },5);
}
```

```css
.contact{
    background-color:red;
    width:30%;
    float:left;
}
.div{
    background-color: blue;
    width: 70%;
    float: right;  
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
                
        <div class="contact" id="contact" onmouseover="myMove()">                    
            <h3> Text</h3>
            <p>More textt</p>
        </div>

        <div class="div" id="div">
            <h3> Text</h3>
            <p>More textt</p>
        </div>                

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks you for your answer, but yes, I do need to do this with javascript.

Comment: @MarioMartin in that case try decrease the width of .div in the interval where you increase side of .contact

Comment: @MarioMartin I edited my answer to use js to give you an idea

Comment: Thank you! I know that I don't need javascript for this, but I want to make a start with javascript. What kind of things on frontend do you really need javascript for?

Comment: for me, it's mostly for editing the dom, ie. adding/removing elements

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with only CSS

```css
.contact {
  background-color: red;
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  transition:1s linear;
}

.div {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 70%;
  float: right;
  transition:1s linear;
}

.contact:hover {
  width: 40%;
}

.contact:hover + .div{
  width: 60%;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">

  <div class="contact" id="contact">
    <h3> Text</h3>
    <p>More textt</p>
  </div>

  <div class="div">
    <h3> Text</h3>
    <p>More textt</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

And for a more flexible way you can consider flexbox where you only need to change the hover element and the other one will shrink by default

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
}

.contact {
  background-color: red;
  flex-basis: 30%;
  transition: 0.5s linear;
}

.div {
  background-color: blue;
  flex-grow:1;
}

.contact:hover {
  flex-basis: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">

  <div class="contact" id="contact">
    <h3> Text</h3>
    <p>More textt</p>
  </div>

  <div class="div">
    <h3> Text</h3>
    <p>More textt</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

**UPDATE**

If you want a permanent change you can try animation:

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
}

.contact {
  background-color: red;
  flex-basis: 30%;
  transition: 0.5s linear;
  animation:big 0.5s linear forwards;
  animation-play-state:paused;
}

.div {
  background-color: blue;
  flex-grow:1;
}

.contact:hover {
  animation-play-state:running;
}
@keyframes big{
  to {flex-basis: 40%;}
}
```

```html
<div class="content">

  <div class="contact" id="contact">
    <h3> Text</h3>
    <p>More textt</p>
  </div>

  <div class="div">
    <h3> Text</h3>
    <p>More textt</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I want to do this with javascript, because I want get .contact get bigger when you over .contact with mouse and if you get of .contact with your mouse, .contact should stay 40% and .div 60%. Is that possible with CSS? or do you know how to do that with javascript? Thank you for your reaction

Comment: @MarioMartin check the update for a CSS solution ... it's good to learn JS but you shouldn't try to do easy CSS things with JS, better do things that really deserve JS

Comment: I know, but I need to start somewhere. What kind of things does deserve javascript in your opinion?

Comment: @MarioMartin everything related to dom manipulation, content changing etc ... but when it comes to visual effect CSS is better. You can use JS for adding/removing classed if needed but it's not good to try changing the width slowly like this when we can easily use transtion or animation

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with Flexbox

`flex: 1` makes `.contact` expand to the rest of the available space.

You would then only need to define the width for `.div` and its width when `.contact` is hovered.

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
}

.contact{
  background-color:red;
  flex: 1
}

.div {
  width: 70%;
  background-color: blue;  
}

.contact:hover + .div {
  width: 60%
}
```

```html
<div class="content">       
  <div class="contact" id="contact">                    
    <h3> Text</h3>
    <p>More textt</p>
  </div>
  <div class="div">
    <h3> Text</h3>
    <p>More textt</p>
  </div>                
</div>
```

Comment: I want to do this with javascript, because I want get .contact get bigger when you go over .contact with your mouse and if you get of .contact with your mouse, .contact should stay 40% and .div 60%. Is that possible with CSS? And/or do you know how to do that with javascript? Because I want to learn javascript, but also wondering wether this is possible with CSS or not. Thank you for your reaction